# GatsbyJS - How can I solve the "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" of GatsbyJS?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, socket.io, gatsby

Note: Thanks @Ferran Buireu for the suggestion. I'm quite sure to get minus vote because of very new to docker and changing network world to system and programming.

After deploy gatsbyjs, I found the socketio error "net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".
Even it works properly when I browse to any pages but I think it is not running correctly.
How can I solve this error? (below is the error capture)

[image]

I implement and deploy these services on Ubuntu 20.04.2 with Docker 20.10.6, please see the below "docker-compose.yml"

```
version: "3"

services:
  frontendapp01:
    working_dir: /frontendapp01
    build:
      context: ./frontendapp01
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - backendsrv01
      - mongoserver
    volumes:
      - ./sentric01:/srv/front
    ports:
      - "8001:8000"
    environment:
      GATSBY_WEBPACK_PUBLICPATH: /
      STRAPI_URL: backendsrv01:1337
    networks:
      - vpsnetwork
  frontendapp02:
    working_dir: /frontendapp02
    build:
      context: ./frontendapp02
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - backendsrv02
      - mongoserver
    volumes:
      - ./sentric02:/srv/front
    ports:
      - "8002:8000"
    environment:
      GATSBY_WEBPACK_PUBLICPATH: /
      STRAPI_URL: backendsrv02:1338
    networks:
      - vpsnetwork
  frontendapp03:
    working_dir: /frontendapp03
    build:
      context: ./frontendapp03
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - backendsrv02
      - mongoserver
    volumes:
      - ./sentric03:/srv/front
    ports:
      - "8003:8000"
    environment:
      GATSBY_WEBPACK_PUBLICPATH: /
      STRAPI_URL: backendsrv02:1338
    networks:
      - vpsnetwork
  backendsrv01:
    image: strapi/strapi
    container_name: backendsrv01
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      DATABASE_CLIENT: mongo
      DATABASE_NAME: essential
      DATABASE_HOST: mongoserver
      DATABASE_PORT: 27017
    networks:
      - vpsnetwork
    volumes:
      - ./app01:/srv/app
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
  backendsrv02:
    image: strapi/strapi
    container_name: backendsrv02
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      DATABASE_CLIENT: mongo
      DATABASE_NAME: solven
      DATABASE_HOST: mongoserver
      DATABASE_PORT: 27017
    networks:
      - vpsnetwork
    volumes:
      - ./app02:/srv/app
    ports:
      - "1338:1337"
  mongoserver:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongoserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - vpsnetwork
    volumes:
      - vpsappdata:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"

networks:
  vpsnetwork:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  vpsappdata:
```

Comment: Can you provide more debugging details? It's impossible to know what's going on with the provided details. "After deploy gatsbyjs" -> where? how? Is your localhost active?

Comment: @FerranBuireu, thank you very much for your reply.
I deploy on my own server with docker.

Comment: The socket connection only appears when using `gatsby develop`, not when you build and "deploy" the site, even locally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The socket connection only appears during the development stage (`gatsby develop`) and it's intended to refresh and update the browser on each saves by hot-reloading, so  without losing component state. This feature is known as fast-refresh.

As I said, and for obvious reasons, this only applies in `gatsby develop`. Under `gatsby build`, there's no connection socket. If your Docker development environment is sharing the port `8000` and `8001` (according to your `docker-compose.yml` setup), once built, can cause a break of the socket because it has changed the scope of the project.

Answering, you don't have to worry about, your project seems to build properly but, because of the sharing port between environments it prompts the log.

Further readings:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/conceptual/overview-of-the-gatsby-build-process/
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/local-development/fast-refresh/